# Scala - Difference between Stream API Filter method vs List withFilter method

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a Scala `List[String]`, i converted the List to Stream using `toStream` method.

```
val list = List("shankar","ramesh","aarush","bujji")
val stream = list.toStream
```

Now what's the difference between these two, both are `lazy` evaluated.

```
println(list.toStream.filter { x => x.equals("bujji") })
println(list.withFilter { x => x.equals("bujji") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One difference is their return type and so what you can do with result. You can pattern-match a `Stream`, take its `headOption`, `mkString`, etc.; the only methods of `FilterMonadic` are `map`, `foreach`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter`.
2. If you assign the result of `list.withFilter` to a variable, and then use it (by calling one of `FilterMonadic` methods: `map`, `foreach`, or `flatMap`) multiple times, it will iterate over the entire list and check the predicate on each element every time; if you do the same with `list.toStream.filter`, it will only iterate over the original list once (and possibly not to the end, depending on what exactly you do).
3. `Stream#filter` is less lazy: it needs to find the first satisfying element (if one exists) immediately.

To see 2 and 3 in action:

```
val listWithFilter = list.withFilter { x => println(s"Checking $x for listWithFilter"); x.equals("bujji") }
val filteredStream = stream.filter { x => println(s"Checking $x for filteredStream"); x.equals("bujji") }

listWithFilter.foreach { x => println(s"listWithFilter contains $x") }
listWithFilter.foreach { x => println(s"listWithFilter contains $x") }

filteredStream.foreach { x => println(s"filteredStream contains $x") }
filteredStream.foreach { x => println(s"filteredStream contains $x") }
```

produces

```
Checking shankar for filteredStream
Checking ramesh for filteredStream
Checking aarush for filteredStream
Checking bujji for filteredStream
Checking shankar for listWithFilter
Checking ramesh for listWithFilter
Checking aarush for listWithFilter
Checking bujji for listWithFilter
listWithFilter contains bujji
Checking shankar for listWithFilter
Checking ramesh for listWithFilter
Checking aarush for listWithFilter
Checking bujji for listWithFilter
listWithFilter contains bujji
filteredStream contains bujji
filteredStream contains bujji
```

Comment: `list.withFilter` will not iterate over the list.

Comment: @Dime _Use_ of `list.withFilter` will iterate over the list.

Comment: Hm. That depends on _how_ you use it. For example `println(list.withFilter(_ => true))` does NOT iterate over the list. `.map` most certainly would ... but so would map over `list.toStream.filter...`

Comment: @Dima I've clarified what I meant.